# I need to move all the variables(x,y,z) to one side of an equality for the equation of a plane

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have `5(x-1)-(y+1)-(z+1)==0`. If I use `FullSimplify` on it it returns
`5x==7+x+y`. This is not what I want: I want it to return `5x-y-z==7`.

Comment: Closely related question: [Is is possible to have mathematica move all terms to one side of an equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4954/245)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
eq = 5 (x - 1) - (y + 1) - (z + 1) == 0
Map[Plus[7, #] &, Expand[eq]]

(*  5 x - y - z == 7  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works nicely:

```
Block[{cf = CoefficientArrays[#]}, Last[cf].Variables[Subtract @@ #] == -First[cf]] &[
       5 (x - 1) - (y + 1) - (z + 1) == 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
expr = 5 (x - 1) - (y + 1) - (z + 1) == 0;
Expand[expr]//.{a_==b:Except[_?NumericQ]:>a-b==0,a___+b_?NumericQ==c_:>Plus@a==c-b}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is

```
body = 5 (x - 1) - (y + 1) - (z + 1);
(#[[2]].Variables[body] == -1*#[[1]]) &@
Flatten[Normal@CoefficientArrays[{body == 0}, {x, y, z}], 1]
```

BR