# Can mathematica simplify an expression setting simplified answer equal to zero?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Basically I want to reduce something like:

```
Subscript[P, 4] - Subscript[P, 5] == Subscript[R, 4, 5]* Subscript[i, 4, 5]
```

when only one of them is known (`Subscript[R, 4, 5] == 1`), so that *Mathematica* expresses the simplified form as:

```
Subscript[i, 4, 5] + Subscript[P, 5] - Subscript[P, 4] == 0
```

Comment: Have a look at `Reduce`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that... But how can you tell it to reduce so you have constants on one side ?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for?  [Is is possible to have mathematica move all terms to one side of an equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4954/281)

Comment: Yeah, but I also have some expressions which equal 1, and I do not want that moved over setting everything to equal zero... 

Basically I want all unknown on one side. And all that's known (defined) on the other side..

Comment: So you have `a - b == c * d` and your only known variable is `c`. Then, according to your last comment, the output should be: `(a - b)/d == c`. That is what you are looking for?

Comment: i have : `a - b == c * d` 

c = 1, 

therefore, by simplifying mathematica outputs: 

a = d + b 

Can i output that as 

0 = (d+b)/a ?
------------------------------

All known on one side, all unkown on the other side...

Comment: using Michael's link `Head[#][Subtract @@ #, 0] &@(a - b == c*d)`

Comment: But still using that method, when I define a, I want it to fly to the left hand side... as I now know this value it's no longer unknown? Does that make sence?

The thing is.. have all these equations ´where a-b==c*d´ and I'm trying to build a matrix, therefore i need to have knowns on one side, and unknowns on the other side.

see this: http://i.imgur.com/jgzo7.png

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `Replace`:

```
p4 - p5 == r45 i45 /. r45 -> 1
(* p4 - p5 == i45 *)

% /. lhs_ == rhs__ -> rhs - lhs == 0
(* i45 + p5 - p4 == 0 *)
```

Comment: (probably the question should have been closed?)