# Square both sides of an equation?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Can I define an equation (for example, `x+1 == y^2 + 2`), and tell *Mathematica* to square both sides?

If not, what is an equivalent way to achieve this?

Comment: I changed the `=` to a `==` as the latter represents equality while the former is used to set a variable.

Comment: A related question you might find useful: [Is it possible to have Mathematica move all terms to one side of an equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4954/245)

Comment: @Jens definitely a good one. Although, there is a built-in function that can handle this while leaving the form intact.

Answer (score 14):

Did you mean this?

```
Power[#, 2] & /@ (x + 1 == y^2 + 2)
```

Or

> `#^2 & /@ (x + 1 == y^2 + 2)`

works as well, according to Vitaliy Kaurov's advice.

> ```
> (1 + x)^2 == (2 + y^2)^2
> ```

Comment: `#^2 & /@ (x + 1 == y^2 + 2)` works too

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov, Thank U for reminding me of it

Answer (score 14):

As this has been answered, already, here is my solution using [Distribute](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Distribute.html):

```
Distribute[ (x+1 == y^2 + 2)^2, Equal ]
(* (1 + x)^2 == (2 + y^2)^2 *)
```

Comment: You could also add `Thread[(x + 1 == y^2 + 2)^2, Equal]` which feels more natural if you want to go that route...

Answer (score 13):

When you have an equation:

```
eqn = x + 1 == y^2 + 2
```

What *Mathematica* actually "sees" is this:

```
eqn // FullForm
(* Equal[Plus[1,x], Plus[2,Power[y,2]]] *)
```

In order to square both sides, you somehow have to "reach into" the `Equal` and square the expressions inside of it.

This can be done with pattern matching, using `ReplaceAll`

```
eqn /. Equal[a_, b_] :> Equal[a^2, b^2]
(* (1 + x)^2 == (2 + y^2)^2 *)
```

You'll notice that this *matches* expression pattern `a_` to `Plus[1,x]` and `b_` to `Plus[2, Power[y, 2]]`.  Then it returns the two, but squared (the `a^2, b^2` part).

Another way to do this would be, as @Jens' link points out, using `Apply`, which passes the sequence of arguments from one function to another (i.e., `g @@ f[a, b]` becomes `g[a, b]` - note `@@` is shorthand for `Apply`.

We use this to our advantage with the pure function which squares both sides of the expression.

```
#1^2 == #2^2 & @@ eqn
(* (1 + x)^2 == (2 + y^2)^2 *)
```