# How do I write a function that can be used in a rule to modify both sides of an equation?

Tags: functions, replacement

I sometimes need fine grain control over equations in *Mathematica* in order to help me understand how to solve a problem manually. A greatly simplified example of a session might be something like this:

```
2x + 3 == 5x - 7
```

> 2 x + 3 == 5 x - 7

```
% /. lhs_ == rhs_ -> lhs - 2x == rhs - 2x
```

> 3 == 3 x - 7

```
% /. lhs_ == rhs_ -> lhs + 7 == rhs + 7
```

> 10 == 3 x

```
% /. lhs_ == rhs_ -> lhs / 3 == rhs / 3
```

> 10 / 3 == x

Instead of constantly writing expressions like `lhs_ == rhs_ -> lhs - 2x == rhs - 2x`, I would like to write function calls like `eqnx[e - 2x]` where the `e` represents the expression being modified and is applied to both the lhs and rhs of the equation.

My intuition leads me to believe that this is exactly inline with *Mathematica*'s strengths, but my rational mind cannot deduce anything close to a correctly working function. Is this possible? Or, should I be taking a different approach?

**Edit**: Xerxes gives an excellent method below for accomplishing this task using the built-in `Distribute[expr, g]` function. Now that I understand how `Distribute` works, I can see that it is very useful. I have been using his technique with a small tweak to reduce the amount of typing required and here is a sample session:

```
eqx[e_] := Distribute[e, Equal]

2 x + 3 == 5 x - 7
eqx[% - 2x]

3 = -7 + 5 x
eqx[% + 7]

10 = 3 x
eqx[% / 3]

10/3 = x
```

The intention of my original question, however, was a rule based technique so that I could more easily work with lines of input or output that already existed (I think my question states this but my detailed description did not reiterate that point). The function approach is efficient as long as you can use `%`, but in most of my work I am iteratively trying different things on the same input and I cannot reliable use `%` and must be remember to grab the correct `In[#]` or `Out[#]`.

Based on the answers to this question and others on this forum, I was able to figure out a rule based solution. While the functionality is similar, the specifics of using the function make for a different user experience. Here is a sample session:

```
reqx[e_] := lhs_ == rhs_ -> (e /. expr -> lhs) == (e /. expr -> rhs)

2 x + 3 == 5 x - 7 /. reqx[expr - 2x]
3 == -7 + 3 x /. reqx[expr + 7]
10 == 3 x /. reqx[expr / 3]
10/3 == x
```

The one issue that I don't understand how to address relates to the placeholder `expr` that I use in calls to the `reqx` function. Inside the function this symbol gets replaced by the `lhs` and `rhs` expressions to produce the result. Its only function is to serve as a placeholder in the expression given to the `reqx` function.

As long as `expr` does not have a value (or rule in Mathematica parlance), everything works fine. Is there something I can do to mitigate or eliminate this potential snafu in usage?

**Edit 2:**
I believe the following definition appropriately protects the placeholder from evaluation:

```
reqx[e_] := lhs_ == rhs_ -> (Unevaluated[e] /. HoldPattern[expr] -> lhs) 
    == (Unevaluated[e] /. HoldPattern[expr] -> rhs)
SetAttributes[reqx, HoldAllComplete]
```

Comment: I intend to close this as a duplicate of [(15311)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15311/121) unless people make a case for me to leave it open.

Comment: @m_goldberg How did you change the markup to produce the alternating colors?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think this question is a more general version of 15311. I also wanted something I could apply as a Rule. Based on the responses I have gotten so far, I now have some ideas on how to do that and will edit my post once I have something working.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't see any particular difference between http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/square-both-sides-of-an-equation and this question, so I'm voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a job for `Distribute`, like so:

```
2 x + 3 == 5 x - 7
Distribute[% - 2 x, Equal]
Distribute[% + 7, Equal]
Distribute[%/3, Equal]

(* 3 + 2 x == -7 + 5 x *)
(* 3 == -7 + 3 x *)
(* 10 == 3 x *)
(* 10/3 == x *)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I read the documentation for distribute, but I am still a little unclear about how this is accomplishing the task. The first call `Distribute[(2 x + 3 == 5 x - 7) - 2 x, Equal]` applies the `- 2x` to both sides of the `==`, but I am not sure why?

Comment: `Distribute` applies the topmost function to a list of expressions contained in some other specified function. The internal form of `(2x+3==5x-7)-2x` is `Plus[Times[-2,x],Equal[Plus[3,Times[2,x]],Plus[-7,Times[5,x]]]]`, which you can see by applying `FullForm` to it. For our purposes, we should think of it as being `Plus[-2x,Equal[3+2x,5x-7]]`. So the top function is `Plus[-2x,...]`. `Distribute` takes that and applies it to each part of the `Equal`.

Answer (score 6):

You can define :

```
f[equation_, transformation_] := transformation[#] & /@ equation 

f[2 x + 3 == 5 x - 7, # - 2 x &]
(* 3 == -7 + 3 x *)

f[%, # + 7 &]
(* 10 == 3 x *)

f[%, #/3 &]
10/3 == x
```

Comment: Is there any advantages / disadvantages to using this function versus the built in Distribute?

Comment: @RandomBits It's just an alternative, I thought it can be generalized if needed.