# Divide both sides of an equation by -2

Tags: algebra

I have:

```
n = Cross[{-1, 2, 2}, {2, 0, -2}];
p = {1, -1, 1};
plane = ({x, y, z} - p).n == 0 // Expand
```

Which gives:

10 - 4 x + 2 y - 4 z == 0

I'd like to divide both sides by -2 to get:

-5 + 2x - y + 2z == 0

Easy way?

Comment: `-#/2 & /@ plane // Expand`. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/square-both-sides-of-an-equation), for instance, and linked questions.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I was looking for.

Comment: @march Interesting. Your technique work, but I had tried `plane/2 // Expand` and got `1/2 (10 - 4 x + 2 y - 4 z == 0)`. Curious as to why?

Comment: Arithmetical operations like `Plus` has the `Attribute` `Listable`, which means that it will automatically `Map` over `List`s, but just as most functions, it doesn't automatically `Map` over anything else. The `Head` of an equation is `Equal` (look at the `FullForm` of your equation), and `Plus[Equal[ ... ]]` won't evaluate. In general, you have to force whatever function you are applying to the expression to move past the `Equal`. I don't think this is explained very well, but I'm a little tired. So it goes.