# Writing System of Equations == 0

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

I have a system of equations and would like to retrieve the Jacobain w.r.t. to some variables. Now I see that this would be best done if I wrote the equations in a form == 0. Is there an easy way to do the latter? (or simply, retrieve the jacobian of this system of equations?).

Example below:

```
systemEq = {x1 == 2 x2 - 1,x1^2 == x2^2 - 4}
```

To make use of the `D[]` function, I imagine that we would have to rewrite this system as:

```
systemEqD = {x1 - ( 2 x2 - 1),x1^2 - ( x2^2 - 4)}
```

where implicitly I am aware that the equations `==0`.

Is there an easy way to proceed? (ideally I would like to scale this for a larger number of equations).
Many thanks.

Comment: The same question has been asked for inequalities, and the answers are basically the same: [Is it possible to have Mathematica move all terms to one side of an inequality?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4954/245)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
Cases[systemEq, Equal[lhs_, rhs_] :> lhs - rhs]
```

> {1 + x1 - 2 x2, 4 + x1^2 - x2^2}

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Probably simpler: `Equal -> Subtract`? (untested)

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `SubtractSides` designed for this sort of thing

```
ClearAll[x1,x2]
systemEq = {x1==2 x2-1,x1^2==x2^2-4};

First@SubtractSides[#] &/ @systemEq
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

And,

```
systemEq = {x1 == 2 x2 - 1, x1^2 == x2^2 - 4};

#[[1]] - #[[-1]] == 0 & /@ systemEq

(* {1 + x1 - 2 x2 == 0, 4 + x1^2 - x2^2 == 0} *)
```